# Gradle API throws error Could not determine java version from '11'

Tags: java, gradle

I try to compile from my code a library using Gradle API.
I have an updated version of Gradle on my machine.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.2.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-02-24 20:24:10 UTC
Revision:     aacbcb7e587faa6a8e7851751a76183b6187b164

Kotlin:       1.3.61
Groovy:       2.5.8
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
JVM:          11 (Oracle Corporation 11+28)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

This library can be compiled in the IDE (IntelliJ).
It's also successfully compiled in the CMD using `compileJava` target.
I use the following code:

```
 public void buildFolderWithCode(Path rootPath) throws RuntimeException {
        // Root path check
        if (!Files.exists(rootPath)) {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("The directory \"%s\" for Gradle build does not exist.", rootPath.toString()));
        }

        ProjectConnection connection = null;
        try {

            connection = GradleConnector.newConnector()
                    .forProjectDirectory(new File(rootPath.toString()))
                    .connect();

            BuildLauncher build = connection.newBuild();

            //select tasks to run:
            build.forTasks("compile");

            //include some build arguments:
            build.withArguments("--no-search-upward", "-i", "--project-dir", rootPath.toString());

            //configure the standard input:
            build.setStandardError(System.err);
            build.setStandardOutput(System.out);

            //kick the build off:
            build.run();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Failed to build with gradle in path \"%s\" (Check the inner exception for further details).", rootPath.toString()), ex);
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        }
```

And I get the error:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not determine java version from '11'.`
How can I pass it `JAVA_HOME`? This environment variable is set on the machine...
I also tried `compileJava` at the target to no avail...

Comment: I'm not talking about the IDE. It compiles at the ide . It doesn't compiles using the Gradle API.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I misunderstood the question. Are you sure the problem is with what Java version is being picked up? Your version output shows Gradle is using Java 11 and the error you get is saying Gradle can't determine the Java version from the string "11". Both those things indicate that Java 11 is being used. Normally that error you're getting means that you're using a _version of Gradle_ that does not support Java 11 (or above). I've never used the Tooling API before though, so I'm not sure why that would be the case nor how to fix it.

Comment: It appeared that the API tooling version was old. I updated it and it solved the issue. Thanks anyway!